# Success Message after uploading using Dropzone in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4, dropzone.js

Am using Dropzone to upload files in Laravel 4.2, Below is my function which process the files after uploading.

```
public function postDropFiles()
{
    $file = Input::file('file');

    $destinationPath = 'uploads/'.Auth::user()->username.'/files/'.date('Y-m-d');

    $extension = File::extension($file->getClientOriginalName());
    $filename =  time().str_random(12).'.'.$extension;

    $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);


    if( $upload_success ) {
        return Response::json('success', 200);//->with('uploaded','Succesiful uploaded');
    } else {
       return Response::json('error', 400);
    }

}
```

The codes works fine , as you can see when response is 200 (success) am trying to pass variable name called "uploaded" (Commented) so that I can display the message to the user that the files successifully uploaded.

In my View I have something like this:

```
@if(Session::has('uploaded'))
    <div class="notice-box"><strong>{{Session::get('uploaded')}}</strong></div>
@endif
```

My aim is to create a session variable after uploading and then use it to display message in View. 
I would appreciate any help. By the way am new to Laravel.

Comment: is it a ajax request or non ajax one?

Comment: It is an ajax request @itachi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### IF USING NON AJAX REQUEST

Add it using the Session facade;

```
Session::flash('uploaded', 'Successfully uploaded.');
```

This will put it in the session for the next request and then be deleted.

#### IF AJAX REQUEST

Pass the message value through the JSON data you are passing back to the ajax request, such as;

```
Response::json(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Successfully uploaded file.'), 200);
```

*Edit: On error as recommended by itachi, this is so the error method in your ajax will be called.*

```
Response::make(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error while uploading file.'), 400);
```

Then you can check the success flag, and then display the subsequent message wherever you want it to display via jQuery.

Comment: Thank you so much..It's an ajax request, and so the second approach worked fine. @Matt Burrow

Comment: __note:__ `return Response::json('error', 400);` don't use it for errors. you are sending a 200 ok header. instead, make a 400 error e.g. `return Response::make(['error occured'], 400);` which will evoke the `fail()` or `error()` or whatever ajax failing callback you are using and you can appropriately take action.

Comment: @105tNoMatter how did you do it?? can I view your code?